# How to retrieve a reference from a boost ptr_vector?

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

I have two classes: an Object class, and an ObjectManager class. The ObjectManager class stores "Objects" via a ptr_vector container. There are some instances where I need to retrieve references to these stored pointers to perform individual actions on them. How would I go about doing so?

Compilable Pseudo Code:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Object
{
public:
  int m_Id;
  Object(int id) : m_Id(id) { }
};

class ObjectManager
{
private:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;
  typedef boost::ptr_vector<Object> ObjectVectorPtr;
  typedef ObjectVectorPtr::iterator ObjectIt;

  ObjectVectorPtr vector_;

  void AddObject(Object *obj) {
    vector_.push_back(obj);
  }

  ObjectPtr FindObject(int id) {
    for (ObjectIt it = vector_.begin(); it != vector_.end(); it++) {
      if (it->m_Id == id) {
        // Found the object...How to return a shared_ptr reference to it?
        // The line below is invalid, obviously:
        // cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Object' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<T> &'
        return *it;
      }
    }

    // We could not find anything.
    return ObjectPtr();
  }
};
```

Basically I want the ObjectManager to retain ownership, but I also want other classes to be able to get a reference to the object, use call methods on that object depending on what's going on, and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your container to use `shared_ptr` as the member:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>

class Object
{
public:
  int m_Id;
  Object(int id) : m_Id(id) { }
};

class ObjectManager
{
private:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;
  typedef std::vector<ObjectPtr> ObjectVectorPtr;
  typedef ObjectVectorPtr::iterator ObjectIt;

  ObjectVectorPtr vector_;

  void AddObject(ObjectPtr& obj) {
    vector_.push_back(obj);
  }

  ObjectPtr FindObject(int id) {
    for (ObjectIt it = vector_.begin(); it != vector_.end(); ++it) {
      if (it->get()->m_Id == id) {
        // Found the object - return a shared_ptr reference to it
        return ObjectPtr(*it);
      }
    }

    // We could not find anything.
    return ObjectPtr();
  }
};
```

btw - prefer `++it` vs `it++` to avoid extra construction, and don't use matching like this if the container gets large - switch to `std::map<int, ObjectPtr>` with `m_id` as the key, or [std::set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8wh7665(VS.80).aspx) with suitably-defined `less` function.

If I was being super-pedantic I would suggest replacing your find loop with a call to [std::find_if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkwky1wa(v=VS.90).aspx), with a predicate that matches on `Object::m_id`...

Comment: Ahh, thanks Steve! Also, if you don't mind answering, when you said "don't use matching like this if the container gets large," are you referring to performance issues?

Comment: @jbaez : yes this is perf-related - matching like this will be O(n) - searching map (binary tree) is O(log n)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a shared_ptr because the object wasn't created as a shared object initially - what would the reference count even be?

You can, however, return an Object* quite easily:

```
Object* FindObject(int id) {
    for (ObjectIt it = vector_.begin(); it != vector_.end(); it++) {
      if (it->m_Id == id) {
        // Found the object...How to return a shared_ptr reference to it?
        // The line below is invalid, obviously:
        // cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Object' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<T> &'
        return &*it;
      }
    }
```